# Javascript canceling previous instances of the same event?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a jqxwidget button with an `onClick` event that takes several seconds to complete.  If the user rapidly clicks on the button, it will create a large backlog of events. Is there a way to prevent this, possibly by cancelling the previous `onClick` event each time the `onClick` event is triggered?

Comment: the best way is to disable that widget on first click and enable after success of the function/task.

Answer (score 0):

use removeEventlistener

```
element.removeEventListener( 'click', func, false );
```

Comment: This would work only for the first click and then the event would need to be reattached.

Comment: maybe add a counter somewhere? and force return false?